# Who are the speakers in John Barth's "Menelaiad"?

Tags: john-barth, lost-in-the-funhouse

"Menelaiad" is a retelling of a Greek myth in which Menelaus, King of Sparta, recounts what happened to him and his crew on their way home from the Trojan war. It's included in the author's short story collection *Lost in the Funhouse*.

Its conceit is that it's a multi-layered story in which a speaker recounts the speech of speakers in the tale who, in turn, begin their own tales within the story and so on. The different speakers are often not named but indicated only by the depth of quotation marks, which alternate " and '. For example (this does contain two names):

> " ' " ' "Seasick," she admitted. "Throwing up." To my just query, why she repaid in so close-kneed coin my failure to butcher her in Troy, she answered-'
> " ' " 'Let me guess', requested Proteus."
> " ' "What I said in Troy." said offshore Helen. "What I say to you now."'

I believe it gets to seven levels deep at one point but in truth, I got lost in this morass pretty quickly. So I went looking to see if there was some kind of diagram or reference somewhere to help identity who was speaking at the different levels of quotation but I couldn't find one.

Can anyone explain or illustrate which character it is that's speaking at each level of quotation marks in the "Menelaiad"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table below explains what is going on at each level of embedded narrative.

| Level | Quotes | Speaker(s) | Situation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | Menelaus | To the reader, in the present of the narrative. |
| 1 | “ | Menelaus | To himself in soliloquy, in the present. This is a bit of a cheat on Barth’s part: there is no need to distinguish Menelaus’s narrative from his soliloquy other than to add an extra level of narration for the confusion of the reader. |
| 2 | “‘ | Menelaus, Helen, Telemachus, Peisistratus | At the palace in Sparta, ten years after the end of the Trojan war. This corresponds to [book 4 of Homer’s *Odyssey*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0136:book=4:card=1). |
| 3 | “‘“ | Menelaus, Helen | At the island of Pharos near Egypt, eight years after the end of the Trojan war, some time after the fight with Proteus (the Old Man of the Sea). This corresponds to [Euripides’ *Helen*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0100). |
| 4 | “‘“‘ | Menelaus, sailors, Proteus | At Pharos, during and just after the fight with Proteus. |
| 5 | “‘“‘“ | Odysseus, Agamemnon, Menelaus, Helen, Eidothea | After the sack of Troy; the first seven years of the voyage home; the landing at Pharos; the advice of Eidothea. |
| 6 | “‘“‘“‘ | Odysseus, Menelaus, Helen | The sack of Troy; the fight at the house of Deiphobus; Menelaus meets Helen after ten years of war. |
| 7 | “‘“‘“‘“ | Menelaus, Helen, Paris | The wedding night of Menelaus and Helen; Paris takes Helen to Troy. |

The structure of the narrative is mostly straightforward, with just one main narrative at each level. Speakers from outer levels regularly interrupt to comment on the inner narratives, but if you count the quotation marks it is not too hard to keep track. It does help, however, to know the story in detail already, by having read Barth’s two main sources.

These are, first, [book 4 of the *Odyssey*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0136:book=4:card=1), in which Telemachus, son of Odysseus, and Peisistratus, son of Nestor, visit Menelaus and Helen at Sparta, and Menelaus tells the story of the sack of Troy, his long voyage home, and the fight with Proteus on the island of Pharos. Second, the play [*Helen*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0100) by Euripides, in which Menelaus meets Helen in Egypt at the tomb of Proteus, and discovers that the ‘Helen’ who went to Troy with Paris, and who has spent seven years on a ship with Menelaus trying to get back to Sparta, is not the same Helen that he married, but a phantom (εἴδωλον):

> ***Helen*** But Hera, indignant at not defeating the goddesses,† made an airy nothing of my marriage with Paris; she gave to the son of king Priam not me, but an image, alive and breathing, that she fashioned out of the sky and made to look like me; and he thinks he has me—an idle fancy, for he doesn’t have me.‡ And in turn the plans of Zeus added further troubles to these; for he brought a war upon the land of the Hellenes and the unhappy Phrygians, so that he might lighten mother earth of her crowded mass of mortals, and bring fame to the bravest man of Hellas. So I was set up as the Hellenes’ spear-prize, to test the courage of the Trojans; or rather not me, but my name. Hermes caught me up in the folds of the air and hid me in a cloud—for Zeus was not neglectful of me—and he set me down here in the house of Proteus, having selected the most self-controlled of all mankind, so that I might keep my bed pure for Menelaos.
>
> <sub>Euripides (412 BCE). [*Helen*, lines 31–48](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0100:card=31). Translated by E. P. Coleridge (1938). Perseus Digital Library.</sub>
>
> <sub>† In the [judgement of Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judgement_of_Paris). ‡ When the ‘Menelaiad’ uses phrases like “decked Helen”, “offshore Helen”, “Helen-on-the-poop” etc. it is referring to the phantom Helen.</sub>

Barth took this idea of the breakdown of identity from Euripides and elaborated on it.

Comment: No this is an excellent answer, thank you for your work in compiling it. I'm only not accepting it to try and help demonstrate the principle that leaving it a few days is good practice.